# npm prune removes used packages, leaving build broken. What is the alternative?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'v noticed weird behavior or `npm prune` in node 5/6 with npm 3.8.6: it removes used packages and leaves the build broken.

Here's dep.list:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.11.1",
    "browserify": "^13.0.0",
    "coffee-script": "^1.9.3",
    "coffeeify": "^2.0.1",
    "cson": "^3.0.2",
    "fastclick": "^1.0.6",
    "gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0",
    "gulp-git": "^1.7.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.6",
    "howler": "github:goldfire/howler.js#2.0",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.0",
    "nouislider": "^8.2.1",
    "parcelify": "^2.1.0",
    "q": "^1.4.1",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.7.0"
  },
```

Results of fresh install:

```
┌(~/Sites/test_client)─(16 files, 280b)
└> nvm use v5
Now using node v5.11.0 (npm v3.8.6)

┌(~/Sites/test_client)─(16 files, 280b)
└> npm cache clean

┌(~/Sites/test_client)─(16 files, 280b)
└> rm -rf node_modules/

┌(~/Sites/test_client)─(15 files, 280b)
└> npm i

> fsevents@1.0.12 install /Users/metalim/Sites/test_client/node_modules/fsevents
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/metalim/Sites/test_client/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v47-darwin-x64/fse.node" is installed via remote
test_client@1.0.0 /Users/metalim/Sites/test_client
├── browser-sync@2.12.5 
├── browserify@13.0.0 
├── coffee-script@1.10.0 
├── coffeeify@2.0.1 
├── cson@3.0.2 
├── fastclick@1.0.6 
├── gulp@4.0.0-alpha.2  (git://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git#b4d89c391b40cd29e8526e0391981eef67cfccab)
├── gulp-git@1.7.1 
├── gulp-uglify@1.5.3 
├── gulp-util@3.0.7 
├── howler@2.0.0-beta12  (git://github.com/goldfire/howler.js.git#db831e03cf696d1ca5cfdd8f87d66e66da2c5029)
├── minimatch@3.0.0 
├── nouislider@8.5.1 
├── parcelify@2.1.0 
├── q@1.4.1 
├── vinyl-buffer@1.0.0 
├── vinyl-source-stream@1.1.0 
└── watchify@3.7.0
```

And immediately after:

```
┌(~/Sites/test_client)─(16 files, 280b)
└> npm prune
unbuild archy@1.0.0
unbuild align-text@0.1.4
unbuild center-align@0.1.3
unbuild findup-sync@0.3.0
unbuild flagged-respawn@0.3.2
unbuild formidable@1.0.17
unbuild interpret@1.0.1
unbuild lazy-cache@1.0.4
unbuild liftoff@2.2.1
unbuild lodash._getnative@3.9.1
unbuild lodash.isarguments@3.0.8
unbuild lodash.isarray@3.0.4
unbuild lodash.sortby@4.4.2
unbuild longest@1.0.1
unbuild mute-stdout@1.0.0
unbuild matchdep@1.0.1
unbuild lru-cache@2.7.3
unbuild os-homedir@1.0.1
unbuild pretty-hrtime@1.0.2
unbuild rechoir@0.6.2
unbuild right-align@0.1.3
unbuild semver-greatest-satisfied-range@1.0.0
unbuild semver-regex@1.0.0
unbuild sigmund@1.0.1
unbuild stack-trace@0.0.9
unbuild tildify@1.2.0
unbuild v8flags@2.0.11
unbuild wordwrap@0.0.2
unbuild wreck@6.3.0
unbuild user-home@1.1.1
```

And the build is broken. What's wrong? Is it npm bug?

After a little bit of testing I found out `npm prune` works as expected only in node versions prior to v5 (npm v3): in v4.4.3 (npm v2.15.1) and below. Basically it does not work with flat dependency lists introduced in npm v3.

What is `npm prune` alternative for flat dependency lists to clean up unused modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering myself.

The problem was in the `npm config` and unexpected dependency of `npm prune` on --depth option.
If you do `npm config set depth 0` to clean up you output of `npm ls` command, `npm prune` gets broken in npm v3+. It seems to take --depth option into account and fails miserably on flat dependency lists.

So, fix for the issue was:
`npm config delete depth`

After that `npm prune` works just fine.

Comment: I will hopefully remember this, one day, when I've been flatlisting my packages for a while using depth 0 :)